# When use PhpStorm edit remote project, how can I ensure the updated files?

Tags: phpstorm

I use PhpStorm SFTP connect to the remote CentOS server for development PHP project.

But I have a question about it: after I edit a PHP file I will sync to the remote server:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

there compare the two files:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

**My question is:** sometimes I updated many files, but I can not remember what files I have changed, how can I update all of them?

Comment: Sure -- `Deployment | Sync with Deployed...` but invoke it on a folder -- IDE will check all files and subfolders in it. You can also check your Transfer log to see what files were uploaded (if you set logging level to Detailed). Alternatively -- why not use Auto deployment -- modified file will be uploaded automatically when it got saved. Please check this link if you have no seen it already: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deployments+in+PhpStorm

Comment: Before asking this question, I tried, but its so slow. can phpStorm check the changed files automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Tools > Development > Automatic upload` In order to upload the files, immediately after the change. I think this method can be useful
[image]